# how do I prevent firefox from upgrading

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

how can I prevent firefox running headless from automatically upgrading on ubuntu 14? I'm using firefox version 47 and I need it to not upgrade automatically to version 50

Answer (score 0):

Firefox - preferences -> advanced - update ( Check for updates / never check for updates ) . This is based on OSX if you are using some other OS it may be little different